# How to display ACF taxonomy field?

Tags: wordpress, autocomplete, advanced-custom-fields, algolia

I have an ACF taxonomy field which is pushed to Algolia.
In the Algolia dashboard I see that field and attributes.

```
rj_narucitelj:[
   {
      term_id: "1444"
      name: "Industrijski park Nova Gradiška d.o.o."
      etc.: 
   }
]
```

How to display rj_narucitelj.name attribute? The code below doesn't work

```
<span class="rj-narucitelj">{{{data.rj_narucitelj.name}}}</span>
```

On the other hand when i try to display author name on the same way it does work.

```
<span class="rj-author">{{{data.post_author.display_name}}}</span>
```

Also, every single field in that indice can display without problems.

I've tried editing the wordpress template, and made a standalone client, but I can't get it work either way.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ovo je trenutno JSON format, prvo se mora dekodirati sa json_decode da dobiješ PHP array, onda prolazis kroz foreach i npr bit ce ovako $data = json_decode($rj_narucitelj)........ foreach($data as $d){ echo $d['name'];}

Comment: OK, I think I understand the principle, but I have no idea how to implement that into dropdown template. How would it look like in the <script> part of the template? Is there any examples or answered questions with this implementation?